# If window has ever been to these coordinates then... if not then

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coordinates, move

I visited theannoyingsite.com and I noticed windows popping up and moving around. (I went there to see if I could get a peek at the source code.)

I am able to do this.

My code is -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>testing123</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="button">testing123</button>
</body>
</html>
```

```
(function() {
var bottomofwin = document.activeElement.clientHeight;
  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "test", "height=120px, width=120px");
    setInterval(function() {
      if(wnd.screenY != bottomofwin) {
      wnd.moveBy(0, 100);
      }else{
      wnd.moveBy(0, -100);
      }
    }, 2000);
    return false;
  };

})();
```

I tried to make a snippet but stackoverflow creates a error. So here is the JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tLf0aey2/ I want it to bounce around the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your window movement is just fine. To make your window bounce you need to keep track of its orientation.

Add a variable

```js
var bottomofwin = window.screen.height; // This worked better for me...
var vertical_velocity = 1 // 1 = Down and -1 = Up
```

Then check whether the popup has hit the upper or lower boundary and change the direction accordingly:

```js
if (wnd.screenY <= 20) {
    vertical_velocity = 1
}
if (wnd.screenY >= bottomofwin - 140) {
    vertical_velocity = -1
}
```

Then use `vertical_velocity` as multiplyer for your `moveBy`

```js
wnd.moveBy(0, vertical_velocity*100);
```

Do the same for horizontal.

Here is my prototype https://jsfiddle.net/sr86zb4L/

Maybe you need to adjust the margins a bit.

Then you are one step closer to be *really annoying* :D